# Sharing audio file on android via skype

Tags: android, android-intent, skype

I use a very simple code to allow sharing of my audio:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/mp3");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilePath()))); //getFilePath() is valid, it works for email and telegram options
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
```

And it works well for Email, Viber, WhatsApp and Telegram options, but when I use Skype I get a toast "Unable to send file". Any tips how to fix it for skype?

Comment: Instead of putExtra() and setType() use setDataAndType().

Comment: Or try with `share.setType("*/*");`

Comment: Doesn´t help.
share.setType("*/*") allow to have more options to share but doesn´t fix skype problem
setDataAndType() breaks even already working Email option, setting a file path as a destination email address with no attachment

Comment: Try using FileProvider instead of sharing a file:// URI. See https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html

Comment: Thanks buddy, it works! I'll accept an answer if you write one